# Why doesn't this work? static $myvar = $my_array[3];

Tags: php, variables

`static $myvar = $my_array[3];`

I've never needed to use the static function until now. But I need to use it to either store the return value from a `function` or an `array`:

```
static $myvar = $my_array[3];

static $myvar = my_func();
```

Why can't I use it like this? Is static only used for intergers?

Comment: Where do you have the information that you should use `static` from?

Comment: Because I want the variable to store the same value when called multiple times

Comment: Static variables can only hold a value of static type, the return value of a function or value of another variable is not static. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are searching for this:

```
function foo() {
    static $counter;
    if(!$counter) {
        $counter = 0;
    }

    $counter++;
    echo $counter;
}
```

Note that beside the usage in OOP programming, the static keyword can be used to declare [static variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) in a function body that should be initialized only once.

So calls to `foo()` will give you the following output, as `$counter` is initialized only the first time `foo()` is called:

```
foo(); // 1
foo(); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PHP Static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Static is for OOP

Comment: Is there a version that I can use for function based php?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't using it correctly. Refer to [PHP.net: Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). You need to be using it inside of a class. And I'm not sure if you need to specify `public` `private` `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

From the page at [Static Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static):

> Static declarations are resolved in compile-time.

See example 7 on the linked page.

This is why you can't assign `$my_array[3]` to a static variable. The contents of the variable is not known at compile time.